# Algolia + Firebase Cloud Functions: index.browseObjects is not a function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, algolia

I am attempting to write a http request cloud function to export indices from Algolia and store them on Firebase Storage, but encountered the above error message like so:

> TypeError: index.browseObjects is not a function

The exporting code is essentially taken from the sample code on Algolia [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/sending-and-managing-data/manage-your-indices/how-to/exporting-index-data-to-a-file/#exporting-the-index). My code as such:

```
//functions/index.js
exports.exportIndex = require('./tests/export_index.f')

//export_index.f.js
const exporter = require('../algolia/exporter')

module.exports = functions.region('asia-northeast1')
.https
.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return exporter.exportIndex()
    .then(() => {
        res.end()
    })
});

//exporter.js
const client = algoliasearch(appId, apiKey)
const index = client.initIndex('the_index')
function exportIndex() {
    let hits = []
    return index.browseObjects({
        batch: objects => (hits = hits.concat(objects))
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Finished!');
        console.log('We got %d hits', hits.length);

        let json = JSON.stringify(hits, null, 2)
        let path = `exports/algolia/the_index/${new Date().toISOString()}/index.json`
        return firebase.saveToStorage(json, path) // file.save() method
    })
}

module.exports = {
    exportIndex
}
```

I have tried similar set of code offline by running `node exporter.js` and the `exportIndex()` function works. However when deployed to cloud function it throws the error. I have checked that my `appId` and `apiKeys` are correct, and that I have enabled Blaze plan.

Any advice?

Comment: At the first look the code seems to be ok... When this error appeared? During deploy?

Comment: The official [Cloud Function sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fulltext-search-firestore/functions/index.js) uses the [Algolia JavaScript API Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/algoliasearch)  (`const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');`).

Comment: @vitooh yes, during deploy. Once it is deployed to Cloud Functions, and when I hit the 'test function' button on the cloud console, it will get this error

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes, `const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch')` is in the code, I omitted from the question for conciseness.